# Magento 2 - Uninstallable set of packages when deploying magento-sample-data

Tags: magento2, composer, sample-data

I've followed [this Magento DevDocs tutorial](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/sample-data.html) to install sample data after installing Magento 2.

But after executing the last command `./bin/magento sampledata:deploy` I get the following error:

```
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
  Problem 1
    - The requested package magento/module-offline-shipping-sample-data could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 2
    - The requested package magento/module-theme-sample-data could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 3
    - The requested package magento/module-sales-sample-data could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 4
    - The requested package magento/module-msrp-sample-data could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 5
    - The requested package magento/module-sales-rule-sample-data could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 6
    - The requested package magento/module-configurable-sample-data could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 7
    - The requested package magento/module-product-links-sample-data could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 8
    - The requested package magento/module-catalog-rule-sample-data could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 9
    - The requested package magento/module-grouped-product-sample-data could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 10
    - The requested package magento/module-tax-sample-data could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 11
    - The requested package magento/module-catalog-sample-data could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 12
    - The requested package magento/module-downloadable-sample-data could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 13
    - The requested package magento/module-cms-sample-data could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 14
    - The requested package magento/module-bundle-sample-data could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 15
    - The requested package magento/module-swatches-sample-data could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 16
    - The requested package magento/module-widget-sample-data could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 17
    - The requested package magento/module-review-sample-data could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 18
    - The requested package magento/module-customer-sample-data could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 19
    - The requested package magento/module-wishlist-sample-data could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.
```

Haven't been able to find a solution and to be honest my knowledge of composer is seriously lacking. Any help would be welcome.

Comment: please see @rnli answer. I think which is the best solution so far. It worked for me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've also been struggling to install the sample data. It appears that somthing is currently broken here (Oct 2015) and the [instructions in the devdocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/sample-data.html) didn't work for me either. I was experiencing the same composer issues and the `magento sampledata:install` isn't even there.

Instead I've been following the "From GitHub Repository" instructions on the [sample data's readme file](https://github.com/magento/magento2-sample-data#from-github-repository):

Just clone the repo somewhere (can be outside your project folder, since the tool is taking care of symlinking the individual modules):

```
git clone https://github.com/magento/magento2-sample-data.git ~/sample-data
```

Then run the "installer" script:

```
php -f ~/sample-data/dev/tools/build-sample-data.php -- --ce-source="$PATH_TO_YOUR_MAGENTO2_PROJECTROOT"
```

After that run the update script:

```
cd $PATH_TO_YOUR_MAGENTO2_PROJECTROOT
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

And you should see the sample data being installed (takes a while...):

```
[...]
Module 'Magento_DownloadableSampleData':
Installing data..
Module 'Magento_ThemeSampleData':
Installing data..
Module 'Magento_OfflineShippingSampleData':
Installing data..
Module 'Magento_ConfigurableSampleData':
Installing data..
Module 'Magento_BundleSampleData':
Installing data..
Module 'Magento_ProductLinksSampleData':
Installing data..
Module 'Magento_ReviewSampleData':
Installing data..
[...]
```

Don't forget to clear caches and fix permissions and you should see all the sample data in the backend and the frontend now...

Comment: But when I run the setup upgrade, Error `PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface' not found` is showing in terminal While SerializerInterface.php file exist.

Answer (score 31):

Had the same problem. Fixed with going to the root directory and specifying the repositories for composer with the following command (use https to avoid composer warning):

```
composer config repositories.magento composer https://repo.magento.com
```

After that

```
cd bin
php magento sampledata:deploy
```

worked as intended

Comment: aha.. beautiful. Worked like a charm

Comment: this should be added to the install/readme.

Comment: would you mind replacing http with https in the link? When I tried the current form my composer refused to connect to it because it's insecure.

Comment: composer config repositories.magento composer https://repo.magento.com/packages.json

Answer (score 4):

In the first section, add `"minimum-stability": "beta"`, before license.

Comment: Did that already but it didn't help, same error

Comment: sampledata:deploy isn't the name of the command, it's 'magento sampledata:install <your Magento administrator user name>'

Comment: @SteveJohnson actually I didn't have the `install` command available

Answer (score 4):

Recent code changes make it possible to install sample data using the Magento 2 CE GitHub develop branch provided you *clone* the Magento 2 and sample data repositories.

This method of installing sample data will be augumented by the time of GA with a command-line option and a Composer option; however, currently, AFAIK, this is the only way to install sample data with the develop branch.

In brief:

1. Clone the Magento 2 CE GitHub repository (develop branch is the default).
2. Run 'composer install' from the project root.
3. Clone the [Magento 2 sample data repository](https://github.com/magento/magento2-sample-data) (develop branch is the default).
4. Link the sample data repositories. (php -f sample-data-repo/dev/tools/build-sample-data.php -- --ce-source="your-Magento-CE-install-dir")
5. Set permissions and ownership in the sample data repository.
6. Install Magento using either the CLI or Setup Wizard. (Setup Wizard no longer has an **Install Sample Data** check box.)

Note that if you run the Setup Wizard, you might see exceptions at about 90% complete. If so, set file system permission and ownership again (most likely as root).

Details: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/web/install-web-sample-data.html

Answer (score 1):

https://packages.magento.com is the old package url for Magento change the composer.json file to https://repo.magento.com

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you can use this alternative too:

```
composer config repositories.0 composer https://repo.magento.com
```

and then:

```
magento sampledata:deploy
```

you'll be prompted for username/password : use **public_key**/**private_key** from your magento marketplace account