# Install Magento EE 2.0.9 Sample Data

Tags: magento2, sample-data, magento2-enterprise

I have a Magento EE v2.0.9 instance running. The install works fine, the site loads all areas fine. I'm trying to install the sample data and I keep running into this issue when running `bin/magento sampledata:deploy`:

`Problem 1
    - The requested package magento/module-gift-card-sample-data could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 2
    - The requested package magento/module-customer-balance-sample-data could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 3
    - The requested package magento/module-target-rule-sample-data could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 4
    - The requested package magento/module-gift-registry-sample-data could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 5
    - The requested package magento/module-multiple-wishlist-sample-data could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.`

In true Magento style the dev docs assume everything is working so I haven't been able to find much on troubleshooting this. Ideally I am looking to install 2.1.1 EE with Sample Data, but I read there is no sample data released for 2.1 yet, so I'm settling for 2.0.9

Answer (score 0):

True, none of our [sample data troubleshooting tips](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/trouble/tshoot_sample-data.html) cover this.

I tried two ways using a Composer installation of EE 2.0.9:

1. Download Magento using `composer create-project`, then run `magento sampledata:deploy`, then install Magento
2. Download Magento using `composer create-project`, then install Magento, then run `magento sampledata:deploy` followed by `magento setup:upgrade`

Both methods worked without errors.

Suggestions:

- Look in `var/composer_home/auth.json` and see if your EE keys are there. If not, [add the file with your keys](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/dev_install.html#create-authjson). It might not be the issue but it will cross that off the list.
- Open your `composer.json` and check the version there. It should be `"version": "2.0.9"`. All of the sample data modules should be there as well.

FWIW, here is mine:

`{
    "name": "magento/project-enterprise-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Enterprise Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "version": "2.0.9",
    "license": [
        "proprietary"
    ],
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "magento/product-enterprise-edition": "2.0.9",
        "composer/composer": "@alpha",
        "magento/module-bundle-sample-data": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-theme-sample-data": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-widget-sample-data": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-catalog-sample-data": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-customer-sample-data": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-cms-sample-data": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-tax-sample-data": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-review-sample-data": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-catalog-rule-sample-data": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-sales-rule-sample-data": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-sales-sample-data": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-grouped-product-sample-data": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-downloadable-sample-data": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-msrp-sample-data": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-wishlist-sample-data": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-gift-card-sample-data": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-product-links-sample-data": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-configurable-sample-data": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-customer-balance-sample-data": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-target-rule-sample-data": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-gift-registry-sample-data": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-multiple-wishlist-sample-data": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-swatches-sample-data": "100.0.*",
        "magento/sample-data-media": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-offline-shipping-sample-data": "100.0.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "1.5.3",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "2.3.*",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "2.2.2",
        "sjparkinson/static-review": "~4.1",
        "fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "~1.2",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.3 <=0.7.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "use-include-path": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": "app/code/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/",
            "Magento\\ToolkitFramework\\": "dev/tools/performance-toolkit/framework/Magento/ToolkitFramework/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "alpha",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    }
}`

Comment: I didn't install using composer create-project and had this problem too. The answer I used, which worked, was: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/86828/46164